# How do I fix Null Pointer Exception when I have already assigned value

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am writing unit testing for a function using roboelectric and facing null pointer exception but I have already assigned the variable.
I'm pretty new to this so if any mistake please pardon me.

```
@Before
public void setup() {

    intent = new Intent(context, Xyz.class);
    intent.putExtra("abc", "abc");

    xyz = Robolectric.buildActivity(Xyz.class, intent)
            .create().start().get();
}

@Test
public void onConfigurationChanged() {
    int currentOrientation = xyz.getRequestedOrientation();
    RelativeLayouot gifframe = xyz.findViewById(R.id.gif_frame);
    assertNotNull(gifframe);
    assertEquals(gifframe.getVisibility(), VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I expect thee gifframe to be able to get the visibility but gifframe is returning a null value. everywhere I searched a solution to this is to assign the value before calling it. I have assigned the value in the previous line.

Comment: It just means that ```xyz.findViewById(R.id.gif_frame);``` returns null, thus there is no ```view``` in ```xyz``` that has the ```id``` of ```R.id.gif_frame```. So make sure you to check what is the value of ```R.id.gif_frame``` and check if ther is a ```view``` in ```xyz``` that has that ```id```. Use debugger for this

Comment: You've assigned *something*. Clearly that something was `null`.

Comment: Yup the value im assigning R.id.gif_frame is null but i'am not understanding why is it null.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `findViewById` is returning `null`. Basically there is no `view` available with given `Id`. That is the right place to debug.

I'd suggest you to attach a debugger and see what is the `view` that is getting loaded and check if it has the desired views.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
 RelativeLayouot gifframe = xyz.findViewById(R.id.gif_frame);
```

Make sure you did `setContentView(R.layout.thefilewhichhas_gif_frame)`

Meaning make sure it knows where it needs to go look for `gif_frame`.

Comment: I tried this but it is giving android.view.InflateException: XML file /home/anirudh/proj/app/build/intermediates/merged-not-compiled-resources/debug/layout/gifframe.xml line #-1

Comment: show us your xml file